# Docker diff images

Tags: docker, diff

I know the question has already been asked (a long time ago), but I cannot find any answer, so I ask it one more time: I have a "complex" (ie deep) tree of docker images locally, and I would like to see the difference between images.

```
[lgmasapp203 ~]$ docker images -t
Warning: '-t' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
├─64e5325c0d9d Virtual Size: 125.1 MB
│ └─bf84c1d84a8f Virtual Size: 125.1 MB
│   └─87de57de6955 Virtual Size: 169.5 MB
│     └─6a974bea7c0d Virtual Size: 291.8 MB
│       └─06c293acac6e Virtual Size: 292.6 MB
│         └─b8a058108e9e Virtual Size: 292.6 MB
│           └─9aa09af53eee Virtual Size: 292.6 MB
│             └─a0513c939a75 Virtual Size: 292.6 MB
│               └─f509350ab0be Virtual Size: 292.6 MB
│                 └─b0b7b9978dda Virtual Size: 292.6 MB
│                   └─6a0b67c37920 Virtual Size: 815.9 MB
```

I already tried `docker save <image-id>` method, then extract the tar file and compare the entries, but what I get is only a bunch of `json`, `VERSION` and `layer.tar` files:

```
[lgmasapp203 ~]$ find 226a
226a
226a/9aa09af53eeee5a36dfd4f0542cf61ec16c3c168e3b6303b49a7bd5b804b1f56
226a/9aa09af53eeee5a36dfd4f0542cf61ec16c3c168e3b6303b49a7bd5b804b1f56/json
226a/9aa09af53eeee5a36dfd4f0542cf61ec16c3c168e3b6303b49a7bd5b804b1f56/VERSION    
226a/9aa09af53eeee5a36dfd4f0542cf61ec16c3c168e3b6303b49a7bd5b804b1f56/layer.tar
226a/e617952427002a05bebf16ba89b0bcaf93a91c786171a6bebedae828ccce7c48
226a/e617952427002a05bebf16ba89b0bcaf93a91c786171a6bebedae828ccce7c48/json
226a/e617952427002a05bebf16ba89b0bcaf93a91c786171a6bebedae828ccce7c48/VERSION
226a/e617952427002a05bebf16ba89b0bcaf93a91c786171a6bebedae828ccce7c48/layer.tar
226a/dddd9e457da7e4ad86d2f6323541bfd439cf290716416a40a9fb4944ecee5c87
226a/dddd9e457da7e4ad86d2f6323541bfd439cf290716416a40a9fb4944ecee5c87/json
226a/dddd9e457da7e4ad86d2f6323541bfd439cf290716416a40a9fb4944ecee5c87/VERSION  226a/dddd9e457da7e4ad86d2f6323541bfd439cf290716416a40a9fb4944ecee5c87/layer.tar
```

I also tried to take a look directly into `/var/lib/docker` directory, but did not find anything.

---

So I started back from "scratch", with a very simple example:

```
[lgmasapp203 ~]$ docker run centos touch xxx
[lgmasapp203 ~]$ docker ps -n 1
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
b43b9b84172f        centos:7            "touch xxx"         7 seconds ago       Exited (0) 5 seconds ago                       backstabbing_hoover
[lgmasapp203 ~]$ docker commit b43b xxx
4b0ed5d4fd1a09e062a02b7066b83115d73a1811863c597f6c5bda01a90507f4

[lgmasapp203 ~]$ docker run xxx ls -l xxx
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul  2 14:31 xxx
```

Everything looks fine, but:

```
[lgmasapp203 docker]# find /var/lib/docker/graph/4b0ed5d4fd1a09e062a02b7066b83115d73a1811863c597f6c5bda01a90507f4/
/var/lib/docker/graph/4b0ed5d4fd1a09e062a02b7066b83115d73a1811863c597f6c5bda01a90507f4/
/var/lib/docker/graph/4b0ed5d4fd1a09e062a02b7066b83115d73a1811863c597f6c5bda01a90507f4/layersize
/var/lib/docker/graph/4b0ed5d4fd1a09e062a02b7066b83115d73a1811863c597f6c5bda01a90507f4/json
```

An I did *not* find anything related to "layer" (as mentionned [here](http://blog.thoward37.me/articles/where-are-docker-images-stored/)). I do not understand why?

Furthermore:

```
[lgmasapp203 docker]# find /var/lib/docker/ | grep xxx
[lgmasapp203 docker]#
```

So where did my file `xxx` go?

It appears to me that this would be a "basic" feature... and then I'm surprised this has not been addressed already...

Does that mean that I have to rely on the "comment" section of the json??? That would be seriously astonishing :-/

I know that is a lot of questions ;-)
Thanxs in advance for any enlightment

Christophe

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't find your file with a find because of filesystem rights.
If you look in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/4b0ed5d4fd1a09e062a02b7066b83115d73a1811863c597f6c5bda01a90507f4` you might find your xxx file.

Comment: I have no `/var/lib/docker/aufs` entry. I am root, so I guess no right issues, and on Red Hat Enterprise 6.6

Comment: Look in other backend storage directory. Maybe it is in a btrfs dir ?